Business scenario on why we need bubble=true and composition=false in LWC
As far as I understood, we need {bubble:true,composition:false} on firing event from child component to parent only when we want the event to be received above in the immediate DOM elements of Parent Component.html (2 div element + 1 child component). my question what could be the business scenario to use {bubble:true,composition:false} ?
Child Component.html:
<template>
    <lightning-card title="My Result">
        <lightning-button variant="base" label="Base" title="Looks like a link" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Child Component.js:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class ApiDecoratorSampleChildComponent extends LightningElement {

    handleClick(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const selectEvent = new CustomEvent('mycustomevent', {
            detail: 'from child',
            bubbles: true , 
            composed : false
        });
       this.dispatchEvent(selectEvent);
       alert('Test2');
    }
}

Parent Component.html:
<template>
    <div onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent1}>
        <div onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent1}>
            <c-api-Decorator-Sample-Child-Component onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent}></c-api-Decorator-Sample-Child-Component>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Parent Component.js
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
export default class ApiDecoratorSampleParentComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track msg;

    handleCustomEvent(event) {
        const textVal = event.detail;
        this.msg = textVal;
        alert('parent ? '+this.msg);
        alert(this.template.querySelector('div'));
    }
}


The main purpose of this configuration is to make more efficient handlers. Your code is too simple to capture this purpose.
Consider a slightly more complicated example. Let's start with an inefficient version of your code where there are five custom child elements:
<div>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent1}>
    </c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent1}>
    </c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent1}>
    </c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent1}>
    </c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent1}>
    </c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
</div>

Using bubbles: true, we can make a more efficient template:
<div onmycustomevent={handleCustomEvent1}>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component></c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component></c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component></c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component></c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
    <c-api-decorator-sample-child-component></c-api-decorator-sample-child-component>
</div>

As you can see, by allowing bubbles: true, you can allow for more efficient event handling. However, this is often not necessary, since most components  speak directly to their parent element. However, because there are exceptions to this general statement, it's useful to be able to handle events more efficiently.
The two main use cases are where you have a component intended to be used in more complicated markup, and you'd like to simplify the event handling at a higher level in the DOM, or you're using either a for:each or iterator:it, and you'd like to minimize the number of event handlers being rendered.
Also, see my other answer here that goes into more detail.

Makes sense now to me. Thanks.
